# mongodb aggregation $sum returning 0 instead of actual sum of integers in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "2023-04-08",
  "dailyNotes": [
    {
      "therapyDiscipline": "PT",
      "individual": [
        60,
        45,
        30,
        75,
        55
      ],
      "concurrent": [
        69
      ],
      "coTreat": [
        67
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to **sum all numbers inside `individual` array and create a new doc with only `individual` key having the sum of array.**

Here's what I have tried so far but didn't work

```
{
$group: 
{
  _id: '$_id',
  individual:{
    $sum: '$dailyNotes.individual'
  }
}
}
```

this returns:

```
{
  "_id": "2023-04-08",
  "individual": 0
}
```

**I don't understand why this is returning `0`, instead it should have returned `265`.**

few other solutions I tried but they also resulted in `0` sum:

```
{
$project: {
  individual: {
    $reduce: {
        input: "$dailyNotes.individual", 
        initialValue: 0,
        in: { $sum: [ "$$value", "$$this" ]}
    }
  }
}
}
```

```
{
$project: 
{
  individual: {
    $sum: '$dailyNotes.individual'
  }
}
}
```

Can someone explains why its returning 0 instead of the 265 and how to fix this?

**[Update]: (example with multiple(max 3) records)**
For a document like:

```
{
   "_id":"2023-04-08",
   "dailyNotes":[
      {
         "therapyDiscipline":"PT",
         "individual":[
            60,
            45,
            30,
            75,
            55
         ]
      },
      {
         "therapyDiscipline":"YT",
         "individual":[
            2,
            4
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

this should return as:

```
{
   "_id":"2023-04-08",
   "dailyNotes":[
      {
         "individual":265
      },
      {
         "individual":6
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: do you only have 1 element inside the dailyNotes array. if not how should it be handled

Comment: dailyNotes array can have up to 3 objects. We can return array instead of a single field if that's what you're asking.

Comment: what i meant when you want to sum how to decide which element to take the sum from. is it the 0th element? can you update the example input doc that handles this as well

Comment: I've updated the question with an example having multiple objs in array @cmgchess

Comment: so daily Notes have to be there if multiple objects and if only 1 object it doesn't?, would be much flexible if the format is same for each cases

Comment: No, dailyNotes will always be there irrespective of number of objects. I want to return in an array.

Comment: ah i was confused with your first output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253633/discussion-between-waleed-ahmad-and-cmgchess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way you can achieve this is using a `$map` along with `$sum`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      dailyNotes: {
        $map: {
          input: "$dailyNotes",
          in: { individual: { $sum: "$$this.individual" } }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X817nn201pp)

an alternative using `$reduce`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      dailyNotes: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$dailyNotes",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ { individual: { $sum: "$$this.individual" } } ] ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bzW739AU8gw)

Comment: dailyNotes array can have up to 3 objects, all of which I need. So I cannot just pick the first one. Instead, we can return an having individual sum values.

Comment: wow this one works smooth, I didn't knew map existed. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: you can also achieve this with reduce. I'll add if i get some time